# How to make ImageButton with 9patch images?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to make that according to size of text on ImageButton this button become wider. But if fails. Here is my code from XML and what I actually see in simulator when text is too long. Images in selector .9patch, how can I make image button to become wider when text is more that image button? Thanks.

```
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/bonjour"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:background="@layout/main_menu_account_white_button_selector"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/bonjour_text_up"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="false"
                android:text=""
                android:textColor="@color/menubutton_black"
                android:textSize="@dimen/small_bottom_menubutton_title_text_size_dn"
                android:textStyle="bold|italic" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/bonjour_text_dn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/bonjour_text_up"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="false"
                android:text="ScreenName"
                android:textColor="@color/menubutton_black"
                android:textSize="@dimen/small_bottom_menubutton_title_text_size_dn"
                android:textStyle="bold|italic" />
        </RelativeLayout>


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <item android:state_pressed="true"
           android:drawable="@drawable/main_menu_account_white_button_1" /> <!-- pressed -->
     <item android:state_selected="true"
           android:drawable="@drawable/main_menu_account_white_button_1" /> <!-- pressed -->
     <item android:state_focused="true"
           android:drawable="@drawable/main_menu_account_white_button_0" /> <!-- focused -->
     <item android:drawable="@drawable/main_menu_account_white_button_0" /> <!-- default -->
 </selector>
```

[image]

Comment: Your image should be a drawable resource, not a layout resource (see android:background attribute of the ImageButton).

Comment: I had try this, but it also didn't help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the workaround which helped me to solve my issue:
I set 9patch image to background of RelativeLayout, removed ImageButton.
Actual button need to be done in such way: 
top & left side = must be marked as scalable only in the middle area
left and bottom = content are must be marked for their all length.

```
            <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/bonjour"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/main_menu_account_white_button_0"
            android:clickable="true" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/bonjour_text_up"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="false"
                android:text=""
                android:textColor="@color/menubutton_black"
                android:textSize="@dimen/small_bottom_menubutton_title_text_size_dn"
                android:textStyle="bold|italic" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/bonjour_text_dn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/bonjour_text_up"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="false"
                android:text="ScreenName"
                android:textColor="@color/menubutton_black"
                android:textSize="@dimen/small_bottom_menubutton_title_text_size_dn"
                android:textStyle="bold|italic" />
        </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep your `9patch` image in the `drawable` folder and make it the source/Background of your ImageButton in the layout.